# Getting response from server using rxjava and retrofit

Tags: php, retrofit, rx-java

i am using rxjava and retrofit to get fetch data from server (localhost for testing) and then show it in recycler view. I have php script which i have tested by postman and its working fine but i could not be able to get this reponse using rxjava. The code i have written is follow.

php script **getPosts.php**

```
<?php
require_once "DbOperations.php";
$response = array();
$response["login"] = array();
$db = new DbOperations();
$user = $db->getPosts();
$response["success"] = "0";
array_push($response["login"],$user);   
echo json_encode($response);
```

The output it give as

```
{"login":[[{"q_contents":"abc","username":"abc"}]],"success":"0"}
```

**ApiClient.class**

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.133:8080/ProblemSolver/includes/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        if (retrofit==null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

In **APiService** Interface

```
@GET("getPosts.php")
Observable<Post> getPost();
```

Model class **Post.class**

```
public class Post {
    private String q_contents;
    private String username;

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(String q_contents, String username) {
        this.q_contents = q_contents;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getQ_contents() {
        return q_contents;
    }

    public void setQ_contents(String q_contents) {
        this.q_contents = q_contents;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**RxJava**

```
private void loadRecentPosts() {
    Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
    mService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    mService.getPost()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Post post) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+post.getUsername(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("", "onError: "+e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}
```

I am getting null in toast message that i have written in onNext().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your json response does not correspond to your `Post` class.

Instead you want to replace your `APiService` with:

```
@GET("getPosts.php")
Observable<PostResponse> getPost();
```

with `PostResponse`:

```
class PostResponse {
    List<List<Post>> login;
    String success;
}
```

and adapt the rest of your code accordingly.